# jQuery: for each set of objects, append to different div

Tags: jquery, html, parse-platform

In terms of jQuery difficulty I'm sure this is super easy. However it's been so long since I've used it I can't remember what to do.

I am using a Parse database and am trying to iterate through each recipe when pulling the data and create a wrap div for each one. See my code below:

```
<h2>Recipes<h2>
<ul id="recipe-list"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        window.console&&console.log('foo');

        Parse.initialize("jX8QururhGgSqp0jfRASN1R9jQBKRDyBUv6SJvBX", "phxNyYWjNCdO38elRqmaPTEmeNAaxE3YCazkWbMd");

        var Recipes = Parse.Object.extend("Recipes");
        var myClassCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({ model: Recipes })
        var Recipes = new myClassCollection();

        Recipes.fetch({

            success: function(collection) {

                // for each recipe, append to the list

                var counter = 0 
                var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');

                collection.each(function(object) { 

                    if (counter <= 10) {
                        $("#recipe-list").append("<div id=recipe>""</div>")
                        $("#recipe").append("<div>" + object.get("name") + "</div>");
                        $("#recipe").append('<img src="'+ object.get("img") +'" />');

                        // $("#animal-list").append("<div class='rec-name'>" + object.get("name") + "</div>");

                        counter = counter + 1
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(colleection, error) {
                // oops an error has occured
                alert(error);
            }
        })

    });

</script>
```

However when I run this I get a result such as:

```
<div class="recipe">
    <name>
    <img>
    <name>
    <img>
    <name>
    <img>
 </div>
 <div class="recipe"></div>
 <div class="recipe"></div>
 <div class="recipe"></div>
```

Where all the recipes are located within one div as opposed to there own.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steve K mentioned above, the id's being duplicated make it impossible to select the right element, so you're just grabbing the first one every time. If you don't need the id's to be on the element, you can just chain the element creation like so:

```
$("#recipe-list").append("<div></div>").append("<div>" + object.get("name").append('<img src="'+ object.get("img") +'" />');
```

If you *do* need the id's, just use the same code but append the id in there like you did the `img` and `name` tags. This is a better solution than traversing the DOM every time, looking for the element by its id. Another alternative is saving the element in a variable and appending to it as so:

```
var recipeElement = $('<div></div');

// you could chain these on the element creation above, like the first example as well and then append it all on the main element below - jQuery is pretty flexible with this stuff
recipeElement.append("<div>" + object.get("name");
recipeElement.append("<div>" + object.get("img");

$("#recipe-list").append(recipeElement);
```

You want to avoid traversing the DOM as much as you can for performance reasons.

Comment: Actually there is one problem I have here. I need the first div appended to be a parent of the object(name) and object(img)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line:

```
$("#recipe-list").append("<div id=recipe>""</div>")
```

You'll notice that you're appending, in each case, a div with `id=recipe`. That leads to multiple divs with the same id. Then in the next line, you try

```
$("#recipe").append("<div>" + object.get("name") + "</div>");
```

And of course, this doesn't work, because there can only be one div with `id="recipe"`. So you need to maybe make the wrapper id a recipe id from the database or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just concatenate the object.id onto the end of the div id:

`$("#recipe-list").append("<div id=recipe" + object.id + "></div>");`

And then:

`$("#recipe" + object.id).append("<div>" + object.get("name") + "</div>");`